# Is this a new way to implement Decorator or Multiple inheritance in Java?

Tags: java, architecture, decorator, multiple-inheritance

**I'm wondering if I found a an alternative way to implement the Decorator Design Pattern in Java? Is this possibly a new way to do something similar to multiple inheritance in Java? Would there be a better way to implement the problem below?**

I'm providing a minimal example, for the following problem (image a simple Game Engine):

- `Actor`: Is a basic actor, which has a position (on the screen) and a flag for visibility
- Some Actors are `Damagable`, which means they are extended by health-points, methods to apply damage and to destroy them (make the base actor invisible) if necessary.
- Some Actors are `Physical`, which means they can have forces like gravity applied, which effectively changes the position of the base Actor.
- Some Actors are `Damagable and Physical`, so they should do a kind of multiple inheritance or apply 2 Decorators (using the Decorator pattern). The `EnemyActor` is an example of this, which of course has additionally its own methods.

Here is my implementation (minimalised):

```
public class Actor {
    int posX;
    int posY;
    boolean visible = true;
}

public class DamagableActorDecoration {
    float health = 10;
    private final Actor base;

    public DamagableActorDecoration(Actor base) {
        this.base = base;
    }

    void applyDamage (float dmg) {
        health -= dmg;
        if (health<=0)
            base.visible = false;
    }

    boolean isDestroyed () {
        return health<=0;
    }
}

public class PhysicalActorDecoration {
    private final Actor base;

    public PhysicalActorDecoration(Actor base) {
        this.base = base;
    }

    public void applyGravity () {
        base.posY--;
    }
}

public interface Damagable {
    DamagableActorDecoration d();
}

public interface Physical {
    PhysicalActorDecoration p();
}

public class EnemyActor extends Actor implements Damagable, Physical{
    @Override
    public DamagableActorDecoration d() {
        return new DamagableActorDecoration(this);
    }
    @Override
    public PhysicalActorDecoration p() {
        return new PhysicalActorDecoration(this);
    }

    public void showExplodingParticleSystem (){}
}
```

Now I can create an Enemy that extends Actor, has its own methods and is also Damagable and Physical. For example by using it like this:

```
public class Runner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EnemyActor enemy1 = new EnemyActor();

        // basic actor behavior : appear
        enemy1.visible=true;

        // basic actor behavior : move forward
        enemy1.posX++;

        // damagable actor behavior : receive damage
        enemy1.d().applyDamage(0.7f);

        // physical actor behavior : fall down
        enemy1.p().applyGravity();

        // damagable actor behavior : be destroyed
        if (enemy1.d().isDestroyed())
        {
            // enemy actor behavior : explode into pieces
            enemy1.showExplodingParticleSystem();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that what you're attempting to achieve here is known as a 'Mixin', and something easily done on the JVM in Scala.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've done is something between delegation and composition. It seems to me that a "Damageable" and "Physical" should behave on their own and have the "EnemyActor" delegate onto them, rather than having the interface delegate onto the decorators.  I cleaned it up a little bit by removing an unnecessary level of indirection.

EDIT: I forgot to mention.  When you're dealing with video games, sometimes performance takes precedence.  If were talking about operations that are triggered by user events, then performance doesn't matter much, however if we're talking about actions that occur many times in a loop -- it may be better to just give in and augment the Actor with direct accessible attributes.

```
public class EnemyActor extends Actor implements Damageable, Physical {

    private final DamageableActorDecoration damageDecorator;
    private final PhysicalActorDecoration physicalDecorator;

    public EnemyActor() {
        damageDecorator = new DamageableActorDecoration(this);
        physicalDecorator = new PhysicalActorDecoration(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void applyDamage(float dmg) {
        damageDecorator.applyDamage(dmg);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isDestroyed() {
        return damageDecorator.isDestroyed();
    }

    @Override
    public void applyGravity() {
        physicalDecorator.applyGravity();
    }
}

public class Actor {
    int posX;
    int posY;
    boolean visible = true;
}

public interface Damageable {
    void applyDamage(float dmg);

    boolean isDestroyed();
}

public class DamageableActorDecoration implements Damageable {
    float health = 10;
    private final Actor base;

    public DamageableActorDecoration(Actor base) {
        this.base = base;
    }

    @Override
    void applyDamage(float dmg) {
        health -= dmg;
        if (health <= 0)
            base.visible = false;
    }

    @Override
    boolean isDestroyed() {
        return health <= 0;
    }
}

public interface Physical {
    void applyGravity();
}

public class PhysicalActorDecoration implements Physical {
    private final Actor base;

    public PhysicalActorDecoration(Actor base) {
        this.base = base;
    }

    @Override
    public void applyGravity() {
        base.posY--;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. This is much better. I don't know why I didn't have this idea before. My extra composition is useless. I'm gonna refactor to this architecture.